# To access multiple tables from a ResultSet

Tags: sql, jdbc, resultset

I have 5 tables, in each table the schema is (com_no,uid,date). I want to access all the tables and get the com_no for same uid. I have written this query in JDBC as

```
String s1= (String)session.getAttribute("uid"); 
rs1=stat.executeQuery("select distinct com_no from hostel,sports where uid='"+s1+"'");
while(rs1.next()) {
out.println(rs1.getString("com_no"));
}
```

But the servlet exception is:

```
The specified field 'com_no' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.
```

can anybody help me to imrove this query or give me some other way to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not a servlet exception it is SQL exception. The SQL itself is not right. When you are querying the database, you have to specify the columns correctly. If com_no is available only in one of the tables then it is fine, else you get error. What is the need of specifying two tables in the select query without any join conditions?

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan I want to print all the com_no present in multiple tables for same uid. So i tried to use this query. Can u suggest some other way?

Comment: which database are you using? With almost all the databases, you can use union,

select com_no from table1 where uid = ?
union
select com_no from table2 where uid = ?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what's your need by retrieving data but you can try the below code which avoid the error which you got now,

```
   rs1=stat.executeQuery("select distinct hostel.com_no as hostelcom, sports.com_no as sportscom from hostel join sports on hostel.uid=sports.uid where hostel.uid='"+s1+"'");

  while(rs1.next()) {
  out.println(rs1.getString("hostelcom"));
   }
```

You must have a look at SQL Join queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` or `JOIN` with alias to avoid not obvious fields in `SELECT` query.

To begin, I would like to know the reason why you have 5 tables with exactly the same scheme?

Comment: I have 5 categories and all need the same attributes.

Comment: Well use `JOIN` in this case. What field is  primary key and foreign key from your tables?